# how to untar all the .tar.bz2 present in subdirectories and create a list of all files

Tags: c#

I am trying to recursively parse a directory ,look for .tar.bz2 files in the subdirectories , untar and create a list of all the files inside the tar file,following is the detailed info,how to accomplish this?

```
path = \\location\tarballfiles\
```

lets say the following .tar.bz2 files are present inside "path" in the mentioned locations

```
RA900B\hw.1\cqq-tech-fw-RA900B_hw_2-DATA.3.4-00028-S-1.tar.bz2  
CQQ9888\hw.2\cqq-tech-fw-CQQ9888_hw_2-DATA.3.4-00028-S-1.tar.bz2
```

......

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
RA900B\hw.1\top.bin
RA900B\hw.1\mtp.bin
CQQ9888\hw.2\test.txt
CQQ9888\hw.2\data.txt
.......
```

PSEUDO CODE:-

```
for each subfolder under path(ignore any files)
    parse recursively to look for .tar.bz2 files
    untar 
    create a list of all the files
```

Answer (score 1):

To find your tarball files in a directory, you can use:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\location\\tarballfiles\\", "*.tar.bz2", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and then recurse the files, open them, untar then and add the files of the tar to a list.

Example (with some pseudo code):

```
var allFiles = new List<string>();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\location\\tarballfiles\\", "*.tar.bz2", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // untar
    var filesFromTar = file.untar();

    foreach (var fileNameFromTar in filesFromTar)
    {
        allFiles.Add(fileNameFromTar);
    }
}

foreach (var allFile in allFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(allFile);
}
```